# Custom GridCellEditor crash python

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to set up a custom GridCellEditor
My config is Windows 7-64 bits, Python3.4.3-32bits, wxPython-Phoenix 3.0.3

I took and adapted sample code from the book wxpython in action.

The CellEditor works fine, but when I try to validate the content (with TAB, or click somewhere else on the grid), Python crashes...

Some other code borrowed from Internet creates the same crash (eg [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxGridCellChoiceEditor2))

Can somebody help me on this ?

```
import wx
import wx.grid
import string

class UpCaseCellEditor(wx.grid.GridCellEditor):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.grid.GridCellEditor.__init__(self)

    def Create(self, parent, id, evtHandler):
        self._tc = wx.TextCtrl(parent, id, "")
        self._tc.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        self.SetControl(self._tc)

        if evtHandler:
            self._tc.PushEventHandler(evtHandler)

        self._tc.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnChar)

    def SetSize(self, rect):
        self._tc.SetSize(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width+2, rect.height+2)

    def BeginEdit(self, row, col, grid):
        self.startValue = grid.GetTable().GetValue(row, col)
        self._tc.SetValue(self.startValue)
        self._tc.SetInsertionPointEnd()
        self._tc.SetFocus()
        self._tc.SetSelection(0, self._tc.GetLastPosition())

    def EndEdit(self, row, col, grid):
        changed = False
        val = self._tc.GetValue()
        if val != self.startValue:
            changed = True
            grid.GetTable().SetValue(row, col, val)
        self.startValue = ''
        self._tc.SetValue('')
        return changed

    def Reset(self):
        self._tc.SetValue(self.startValue)
        self._tc.SetInsertionPointEnd()

    def Clone(self):
        return UpCaseCellEditor()

    def StartingKey(self, evt):
        self.OnChar(evt)
        if evt.GetSkipped():
            self._tc.EmulateKeyPress(evt)

    def OnChar(self, evt):
        key = evt.GetKeyCode()
        if key > 255:
            evt.Skip()
            return
        char = chr(key)
        if char in string.ascii_letters:
            char = char.upper()
            self._tc.WriteText(char)
        else:
            evt.Skip()


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Grid Editor",
                             size=(640,480))
        grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(50,50)
        grid.SetCellEditor(0, 0, UpCaseCellEditor())

app = wx.App()
frame = TestFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I've tried with PyGridCellEditor (which is said to be deprecated ?)

```
>>> import wx
>>> wx.grid.PyGridCellEditor
class 'wx.core.deprecated.locals.DeprecatedClassProxy'
```

Btw, I get the same problem with PyGridCellEditor. As python crashes, I don't get any traceback from idle. The only information I have is from Windows:

`Signature du problème :
  Nom d’événement de problème:  APPCRASH
  Nom de l’application: pythonw.exe
  Version de l’application: 0.0.0.0
  Horodatage de l’application:  54ecf082
  Nom du module par défaut: _core.pyd
  Version du module par défaut: 0.0.0.0
  Horodateur du module par défaut:  55cb1a46
  Code de l’exception:  c0000005
  Décalage de l’exception:  00012fa5
  Version du système:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Identificateur de paramètres régionaux:   2060
  Information supplémentaire n° 1:  0a9e
  Information supplémentaire n° 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Information supplémentaire n° 3:  0a9e
  Information supplémentaire n° 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789`

If there is something I can do to have more informations, juste tell me :)

Comment: The only problem I see is that this code doesn't run. It should be using `PyGridCellEditor` instead of `GridCellEditor`. Could you post your traceback or error message so we can try to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: I made some updates to the questions, can I do more to help for trying to solve the problem ? Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the solution:
EndEdit actually takes one more positional argument oldval
So, replacing

```
def EndEdit(self, row, col, grid):
```

with

```
def EndEdit(self, row, col, grid, oldval):
```

do the trick. The code could also be improved with this argument, I think.
Beside, ApplyEdit(self, row, col, grid) should be overridden, and this is where the actual change to the table should be made...